На время поменять поток, реклама в видео
Для того, чтобы показать рекламу пользователю. Всегда генерировал новый тег video, подгружал видео и запускал...
Недавно стал копаться в
https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/index.html
Вопрос в том, как в данном случаи быть с показом рекламы. Быть может при работе с dash, возможно поменять поток на время(показать рекламу). А затем вновь продолжить просмотр ролика...
Не создавая дополнительный интерфейс под рекламу, не создавая тега video и тп...
